# Python modifying the local variable in function

Tags: python, variables, binding

I have a school project in which we are making custom text based database.

I have this function :

```
def setRecord(self,mySliceRecord):
    print("In setRecord :",mySliceRecord.record)
    self.readDB()
    print("In setRecord after reading:",mySliceRecord.record)

    if self.dbSchema.dbIndex:
        self.dbData[mySliceRecord.record[self.dbSchema.dbIndex]] = mySliceRecord
    else:
        self.dbData.append(mySliceRecord)
    return True
```

From this I am calling readDB() which is :

```
def readDB(self):
    dictCounter = 0
    if self.dbSchema.dbIndex:
        self.dbData = dict()
    else:
        self.dbData = list()
    file = open(self.dbName+'.apd')
    for line in file:
        counter = 0
        splittedLine = line.split("|")
        sliceRecord = SliceRecord(self.dbSchema.schema)

        for item in splittedLine:
            if item:
                sliceRecord.record[self.dbSchema.schemaList[counter]] = item.strip()
            counter += 1
        if self.dbSchema.dbIndex:
            self.dbData[sliceRecord.record[self.dbSchema.dbIndex]] = sliceRecord
        else:
            self.dbData.append(sliceRecord)
```

Now whats happening is somehow, `mySliceRecord` in `setRecord()` getting modified. This is a custom object of my class `SliceRecord()`, which has two `orderedDicts`.

The output for the print statements is this :

In `setRecord`: `OrderedDict([('Name', 'asdklajsweq'), ('Age', 123), ('Email', 'asdasqweqwe')])`

In `setRecord` after reading: `OrderedDict([('Name', ''), ('Age', '18'), ('Email', 'asdasd')])`

The dict which is being displayed after `self.readDB()` call is actually last record in the text file.

It probably has something to do with binding, but what I don't understand is that `mySliceRecord` variable name is not used anywhere else. Any help is appreciated. :)

UPDATE : My `readDB()` method is not working as expected as well, all the records show same data.

Output of `self.dbData` after reading through File :

`Record :  OrderedDict([('Name', 'Hello'), ('Age', '20'), ('Email', 'Next')])
Record :  OrderedDict([('Name', 'Hello'), ('Age', '20'), ('Email', 'Next')])`

While in file I have two different records, the record repeated here is the last record in the file. I am not understanding the memory allocation properly and copying. :-|

PS : Don't thrash me, I am coding on python for second time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, the problem was actually in the SliceRecord class implementation, where I have never initialized dict() inside the **init** but in the class directly, hence I had kind of a static class variable. I know stupid me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating the state of `mySliceRecord` in `readDB()`. Python objects are references, which means that mutable objects passed to other functions can be modified, **even if the variable itself is not being set**. If you add `mySliceRecord` to `self.dbData`, read it back from `self.dbData` in `readDB()`, and modify it, you'll see the modifications in `setRecord` as well.

Simple example:

```
def foo(l):
    l.append("foo")

x = []
foo(x)
print(x)  # ['foo']
```

Comment: Ahhh ok ok.. Thanks a lot.. I think python probably has adhoc binding, but this feature is weird, any suggestion how this can be avoided? I just dont want to call readDB() from init method, I just want to call it only when I need to read the data.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh For simple cases like these you just need to take this into account when you're writing code and not unexpectedly mutate shared objects. For more complex cases another popular approach is to use immutable data structures, where your data structures expressly disallow themselves to be modified and instead return new copies with modifications applied when necessary.